# convert the output of KMO to matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to create a  KMO output to matrix to save it in excel file

for eg:

```
QUEST <- data.frame(
  Q1=c(1,5,2,3,4,2,3,4,3,2), 
  Q2=c(2,4,1,2,4,1,2,5,2,1), 
  Q3=c(2,5,1,3,3,2,2,4,2,2))
#install.packages("psych")
library(psych)
T1 <- cor(QUEST)
T2 <- KMO(T1)
```

now i want the T2 output should be matrix so that i can save it in excel file, please help

Comment: I want to save the anti correlation matrix in excel (T2)

Comment: @IanCampbell  my next requirement would be  T2 %>% as.data.frame()  then left join with other data frames to map columns and then save the xlsx file

Comment: @PKumar  my next requirement would be  T2 %>% as.data.frame()  then left join with other data frames to map columns and then save the xlsx file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`help(KMO)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/2.0.12/topics/KMO):

> Details
>
> Let S^2 = diag(R^{-1})^{-1} and Q = SR^{-1}S. Then Q is said to be the anti-image intercorrelation matrix.
>
> ...
>
> Image The Image correlation matrix (Q)

To print the "anti-image intercorrelation matrix":

```
T2$Image
#           Q1         Q2         Q3
#Q1  1.0000000 -0.3514537 -0.5093882
#Q2 -0.3514537  1.0000000 -0.4930078
#Q3 -0.5093882 -0.4930078  1.0000000
```

Or to write it to Excel:

```
library(openxlsx)
openxlsx::write.xlsx(T2$Image,"Matrix.xlsx")
```

Comment: my next requirement would be T2 %>% as.data.frame() then left join with other data frames to map columns and then save the xlsx file